# SAS search and replace the last word using regex

Tags: regex, sas

I'd like to search and replace the last word using regex in SAS.

Example:
"cat is cute"
"this is a cat"

Here I want to change "cat" -> "dog", but only if "cat" is the last word (in this example the second sentence)

This is what I have so far:

```
data regextest;
    input sentence $25.;
    datalines
;
    cat is cute
    this is a cat
;
run;


data regextest2;
    set regextest;
    sentence2 = prxchange("s/cat$/dog/", -1, sentence);
run;
```

But this is not giving me the result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use `"s/cat\s*$/dog/"`

Comment: Oh it works! Thank you so much!